# How to rename System Tables Name in SQL-Server_2014?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Can we change System Table names in sql server?  If yes then guide me how to do that.

Also, how can I unmark system table?  i.e. can I move a table from system tables to user-defined table?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Table SQL Server is permanent and can not be replaced, but there are some software (third parties) that can rename tables in SQL Server or Solution #2 is export your database into the form of .sql and edit the table name from the .sql then import

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply but there's is an store procedure by which we can mark a user defined table as system tables . but how can i revert back ? means i can move a table from user defined to system tables but how can i revert back this activity?

Comment: So you want to mark the system table to be different from other tables?

Comment: by sp_rename  we can rename any user defined table but my concern is how can i rename system table or move system table into user defined table

Comment: Sorry I have never done that before, maybe if you search deeper you will find it